# How do I find out what is happening during an upgrade

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

I was running 17.04 on my really ancient 256Mb PIII.  I use it mainly for reading pdf docs while I'm programming on other machines.  Since 2 years ago, it has been coming up with a software upgrade icon.  I decided to update 18.04 two days ago.  I know 19.04 is out but it did not give me that option.

Went through a question and answer session and then a reset.  After booting up, nothing has appeared on the screen since the reset.  The disk light flashes occasionally so I assume it is doing something.

Is there anything key sequence I can press (I've tried all the function keys already) to get it to show me what it is doing?   I'd just to know what it is doing.

Comment: Yes it partially answers the question.  I pressed ctrl-alt-F1 - got a login prompt.  Logged in and it went straight back to the black screen.  Pressed ctrl-alt-f1 again and typed unity.  Went straight back to black screen.   I'll give it a bit more time.  If it doesn't work, I'll reinstate 17.04 since all I'm using it for is reading PDFs.

Comment: It finally finished the update after chugging away for 36 hours.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know what the upgrade is doing? This is usually printed in the terminal if that's where you 
Sudo apt update &&
Sudo apt upgrade &&
Sudo apt install dist-upgrade

Then hear should  be the output of updated repository (ies)
The upgrade what's being installed as the upgrade an  then the distribution upgrade output linux headers etc

apt-list --upgradeable will give u all the packages upgrade will upgrade, hope this helps

Comment: This is the upgrade after it asks "OK to reboot".  It has rebooted and is doing something to upgrade the OS but it isn't telling me what it is doing.  There is no terminal prompt.  Just a blank screen with a flashing cursor.  Whatever I type doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: Press alt+f7 or f+7 or ctrl+alt+f7 and variations or try f2 see if u can log in to a tty and startx or what ever windows server it using